# get value of textbox when maxlength is crossed

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a textbox which is having a maxlength of 5. Now on keyup event I check some logic. Say user presses 6th number in keyup event I get value of (5th) precison only as maxlength allowed is upto 5 only.

How can I check value which is entered latest?

```
 <td class="Input">
     <div id="d1" css-class="l1" numeric="{min: 0.0, max: 0.0, step: '1.0'}" ng-model="select"
     decimalplace="1" maxlength="5" disabled="true" spinner-spin="updateSeamCompensation(event,value)" d1-keyup="d1Inputkeyup(event,value)"/>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put up a limitation of MaxLength on text box then you will not get character located at position 6. You have to choose other event which can get value before add up in textbox.

You can use "KeyDown" event for that.

If that not work then lets take one more hidden text box with no max length constraints and you can put up a check if string length is more then 5 then value will not get inserted in actual text box.

Here is the example:

```
function edValueKeyPress()
    {
        var hiddenTextBoxStr = document.getElementById("edValue").value;

        if(hiddenTextBoxStr.length<=5)
        {
            actualTextbox.text=hiddenTextBoxStr;
        }  
        else
        {
            alert(hiddenTextBoxStr.charAt(hiddenTextBoxStr.length));
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes after max length i tried to get value in console in all key events.. all have same value of max 5

Comment: @sameer, please mark it as answer so it will help others too. If you find it useful